# Filtering data on the basis of code and date

Tags: r, excel, stata

I have the following dataset:

```
id   code        date   charge  
 1    AAA   01jan2016       23  
 1    BBB   20jan2016       45  
 1    CCC   19feb2018       23  
 1    DDD   20jan2019      123  
 1    EEE   02jan2016       43  
 1    FFF   12dec2015       12  
 2    AAA   07jan2017       12  
 2    BBB   08jan2017       32  
 2    CCC   06jan2017       12  
 2    DDD   10oct2019       12  
 3    AAA   12dec2014       12  
 3    BBB   18dec2014       12  
 3    CCC   01dec2014       13
```

How can I keep all the records, which are within `-30` to `+90` days of code `AAA`?

This is the output I expect:

```
id   code        date   charge  
 1    AAA   01jan2016       23  
 1    BBB   20jan2016       45  
 1    EEE   02jan2016       43  
 1    FFF   12dec2015       12  
 2    AAA   07jan2017       12  
 2    BBB   08jan2017       32  
 2    CCC   06jan2017       12  
 3    AAA   12dec2014       12  
 3    BBB   18dec2014       12  
 3    CCC   01dec2014       13
```

I tried to use the filter of date but the date of `AAA` is different for all ID's so it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to first convert the 'Date' to `Date` class (`mdy` - from `lubridate`), then grouped by 'ID', check whether the 'Date' values are `between` the 30 days before the 'Date' on which 'Code' is "AAA" and within 90 days after that 'Date'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(between(Date, min(Date[Code == "AAA"]) - days(30),
             min(Date[Code == "AAA"]) + days(90)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID Code  Date       Charge
#   <int> <chr> <date>      <dbl>
# 1     1 AAA   2016-01-01     23
# 2     1 BBB   2016-01-20     45
# 3     1 EEE   2016-01-02     43
# 4     1 FFF   2015-12-12     12
# 5     2 AAA   2017-01-07     12
# 6     2 BBB   2017-01-08     32
# 7     2 CCC   2017-01-06     12
# 8     3 AAA   2014-12-12     12
# 9     3 BBB   2014-12-18     12
#10     3 CCC   2014-12-01     13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), Code = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", 
"AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), Date = c("1/1/2016", 
"1/20/2016", "2/19/2018", "1/20/2019", "1/2/2016", "12/12/2015", 
"1/7/2017", "1/8/2017", "1/6/2017", "10/10/2019", "12/12/2014", 
"12/18/2014", "12/1/2014"), Charge = c(23, 45, 23, 123, 43, 12, 
12, 32, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A Stata solution is the following:

```
clear
input byte id str3 code float date int charge
1 "AAA" 20454  23
1 "BBB" 20473  45
1 "CCC" 21234  23
1 "DDD" 21569 123
1 "EEE" 20455  43
1 "FFF" 20434  12
2 "AAA" 20826  12
2 "BBB" 20827  32
2 "CCC" 20825  12
2 "DDD" 21832  12
3 "AAA" 20069  12
3 "BBB" 20075  12
3 "CCC" 20058  13
end
format %td date

bysort id (code date): generate delta = date - date[1]
keep if delta >= -30 & delta <= 90
```

Results:

```
list, sepby(id)

     +----------------------------------------+
     | id   code        date   charge   delta |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |  1    AAA   01jan2016       23       0 |
  2. |  1    BBB   20jan2016       45      19 |
  3. |  1    EEE   02jan2016       43       1 |
  4. |  1    FFF   12dec2015       12     -20 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  5. |  2    AAA   07jan2017       12       0 |
  6. |  2    BBB   08jan2017       32       1 |
  7. |  2    CCC   06jan2017       12      -1 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  8. |  3    AAA   12dec2014       12       0 |
  9. |  3    BBB   18dec2014       12       6 |
 10. |  3    CCC   01dec2014       13     -11 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```